# Get most recent job's data for all unique jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a hard time figuring out where the problem is in my code. I Have a few jobs running periodically at different frequencies. From those jobs I need data for most recent job running data for all unique jobs from Jobs Table.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Jobs - Master Table

```
Job_Id    Name
1   Job1
2   Job2
3   Job3
```

Jobs history

```
Id        Job_Id      StartTime                       EndTime 
100       1       2015-03-11 16:03:49.760     2015-03-11 16:09:49.760   
101       2       2015-03-10 16:03:49.760     2015-03-10 16:40:49.760
102       3       2015-02-11 16:03:49.760     2015-02-11 16:09:49.760
103       2       2015-03-11 16:03:49.760     2015-03-11 16:09:49.760
104       1       2015-03-11 16:08:49.760     2015-03-11 16:12:49.760
105       1       2015-03-11 16:12:49.760     2015-03-11 16:16:49.760
106       1       2015-03-11 16:20:49.760     2015-03-11 16:29:49.760
```

Output: I Need something like below. Most recent Job data for each job. Each job frequency is not the same.

```
Id          Name    StartTime                             EndTime
106       Job1       2015-03-11 16:20:49.760     2015-03-11 16:29:49.760
103       Job2       2015-03-11 16:03:49.760     2015-03-11 16:09:49.760
102       Job3      2015-02-11 16:03:49.760     2015-02-11 16:09:49.760
```

---

```
  SELECT top 1* FROM  Jobs  j
  INNER JOIN  JobsHistory jh ON j.Id = jh.Job_Id
  where jh.Job_Id in (select Id from Jobs )
  order by jh.starttime desc
```

Comment: @Siyual:Thanks for editing the data. Unfortunately I couldn't able to. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

The `ROW_NUMBER()` with the `OVER()` clause will number you jobs, sorted by the StartTime (descending) and do this numbering partitioned for each Job_Id. All rows with the number 1 should be the most recent per Job_Id

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Job_Id ORDER BY StartTime DESC) AS OrderNr
          ,*
    FROM  Jobs  j
      INNER JOIN  JobsHistory jh ON j.Id = jh.Job_Id
) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.OrderNr=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately I don't have access to connect to database remotely. I will test it on Monday morning once I am in offic and let you know.

Comment: I couldn't wait until Monday morning to see the results. I have created SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/945e1/1 to replicate and it is working perfectly. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: your solution is working well. But it is taking 10-12 secs when I query a huge table. I found another way to query using CTE, it is much faster(<1 sec). Just wanted to share. So that it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Shnugo is working fine, but it is slow. I found another way to query using CTE, it is much faster(<1 sec). Just wanted to share the query to help others.

```
WITH JH_CTE(Id, RecentRunId) AS (SELECT Job_Id, max(Id) FROM JobsHistory GROUP BY Job_Id)
SELECT * from Jobs j
JOIN JH_CTE on j.Job_Id = JH_CTE.Id
JOIN JobsHistory jh on jh.Id = JH_CTE.RecentRunId
```